# Objective c - new UILabel text is 'merged' with the existing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I am refactoring an 'old' Objective-C iOS-program. All layout is done programmatically without storyboard.

I am experiencing some odd behavior when I try to update the text on a UILabel. The text is NOT updated but written 'on top' of the existing text.

The context is:

The UILabel is defined in a 'top-bar' that is managed by a sub-ViewController. It is assigned as 'default'/placeholder value when initialized by the sub-ViewController.

```
lblArea = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
//self.lblArea.text = @"giraf";
lblArea.textColor       = BLACK_COLOR;
lblArea.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
lblArea.textAlignment   = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
lblArea.font            = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:14];
//self.lblArea.text=SEARCH_FOR_ADDRESS;

NSAttributedString *placeholderText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:SEARCH_FOR_ADDRESS attributes : @{
               NSForegroundColorAttributeName : GRAY_COLOR,
                }];

lblArea.attributedText=placeholderText;


[self.view addSubview:lblArea];
```

The setter-method is

```
-(void)setLabelAreaText:(NSString *)labelText{
lblArea.text=labelText;
}
```

In the parent controller the sub-controller is added as follows:

```
[self addChildViewController:topBarViewController];
[topBarViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self.view addSubview:[topBarViewController view]];
```

When the label is assigned another value from the parent-ViewController (via a setter method) the text is not replaced but written 'on top' of the existing.

The UILabel is defined as a instance variable and is made accesiable via a custom setter-method. I have tried to change it to a public property but it doesn't change anything.

Can anyone please help with an explanation :-)

Comment: How about you post the contents of the setter method?

Comment: did you try to set it through `lblArea.attributedText` instead of `lblArea.text`? It's just a wild guess, but I would start with that..

Comment: Can we see on how you add this to your view

Comment: I have tried to add it as both text and attributedText. But it doesn't do any difference

Comment: Try to post more about the "sub-viewController" and the method you set a new value to the label in your "parent-viewController". I guess whether you have made a new label when you set a new value to the label